# Explode data / transform it to the PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

My data variable is following:

```
 canv = 2,3,4,5:::canp = 2,3,4:::canpr = 2,3,4:::canpp = 2,3,4:::all = 2,3,4
```

I need it to transform to an array which should look following:

```
$arr = array(
"canv" => array("2", "3", "4", "5"),
"canp" => array("2", "3", "4"),
"canpr" => array("2", "3", "4"),
"canpp" => array("2", "3", "4"),
"all" => array("2", "3", "4")
);
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = "canv = 2,3,4,5:::canp = 2,3,4:::canpr = 2,3,4:::canpp = 2,3,4:::all = 2,3,4";
$result = array();
foreach (explode(':::', $data) as $line) {
    list($part1, $part2) = explode(' = ', $line);
    $result[$part1] = explode(',', $part2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But now, I want to read if the key exist in the array this way: `if(isset($result["canv"][$gid]))` (where $gid is group id that is in the array), but it's not working because array looks like this:
`array("canv" => array(1 => "2", 2 => "3", 3 => "4", 4 => "5");` I need it to look like this:
`array("canv" => array("2", "3", "4", "5");`

How can it be done?

Comment: `if (isset($result['canv']) && in_array($gid, $result['canv']))`

Comment: You can't make the array look exactly like `array("2", "3", "4", "5")`, there must be indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
$data = "canv = 2,3,4,5:::canp = 2,3,4:::canpr = 2,3,4:::canpp = 2,3,4:::all = 2,3,4";
$items = explode(":::", $data);
$arr = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
    $item = explode(" = ", $item);
    $arr[$item[0]] = explode(",", $item[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But now, I want to read if the key exist in the array this way: `if(isset($result["canv"][$gid]))` (where $gid is group id that is in the array), but it's not working because array looks like this:
`array("canv" => array(1 => "2", 2 => "3", 3 => "4", 4 => "5");` I need it to look like this:
`array("canv" => array("2", "3", "4", "5");`

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
$orig_str = 'canv = 2,3,4,5:::canp = 2,3,4:::canpr = 2,3,4:::canpp = 2,3,4:::all = 2,3,4';

$parts = explode(':::', $orig_str);

$data = array()
foreach($parts as $key => $subparts) {
    $data[$key] = explode(',', $subparts);
}
```

Comment: Woops...right. Ah well, I'll take the math textbook way out and say that it's left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this: this is not tested, try to print_r to debug

```
$string = "canv = 2,3,4,5:::canp = 2,3,4:::canpr = 2,3,4:::canpp = 2,3,4:::all = 2,3,4";

$pieces = explode(':::',$string);
$result = array();
foreach($pieces AS $piece)
{
   $tmp = explode(' = ',$piece);
   $result[$tmp[0]] = explode(',',$tmp[1]);
}
```